# Django forms: display label next to field instead of above it

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm using `{{ form.as_p }}` to show my form, it ends with displaying:

```
   Label:
   |||||||||||||||||||||||
```

what I would like to see is:

```
   Label: |||||||||||||||||||||||
```

Is there a way to accomplish that with CSS or Django?

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is to use django templates and of course html/css.

for example do as follow:

```
{% for field in forms.fields %}
    <p><b>{{field.label}}</b>: {{field}}
{% endfor %}
```